# C++ Error: no match for call to ‘(std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}) (std::string&)’

Tags: c++, string, constructor, compiler-errors, initialization

I'm new to C++. I search many times, but still can't get the answer. I'm writing a class named Course to describe the courses students taking at school. The Course class has 3 fileds:

```
protected:
    string courseName;
    int courseNum;
    float score;
```

And I have a public method "setName" to set the course name:

```
Course &setName(string name)
{
    this->courseName(name);
    return (*this);
}
```

However, when I tried to compile, the compiler complains that:
**C++ Error: no match for call to ‘(std::string {aka std::basic_string}) (std::string&)’**
I also tried to modify the code to **Course &setName(string &name)...** And the compiler keeps complaining about the same error.

But if I change the code to:

```
Course &setName(string name)
{
    this->courseName = name;
    return (*this);
}
```

Then it works well. I couldn't understand what the compiler is complaining about and why I can't use the direct initialization?

Comment: The first example is trying to invoke a function call operator. `std::string` does not declare this operator which results in the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I couldn't understand what the compiler is complaining about and why I can't use the direct initialization?

Because that's not an initialization. That's an assignment. Both assignment an (copy-)initialization make use of the `=` sign, but don't let that fool you: the two things are fundamentally different.

Initialization is what gives a value to an object **upon construction**. When your `setName()` member function gets called, the object on which it is invoked (as well as its data members) have already been constructed. If you want to initialize them there, you're late: you've missed the train.

In a constructor's *initialization list*, on the other hand, you could initialize your data members as follows:

```
Course::Course(std::string name) : courseName(std::move(name)) { }
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                 This would be initialization
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, I see where the problem is. I don't quite understand if "string str = "hello" " is another kind of initialization? Can the =operator be used to do initialization?

Comment: @Dreamer: When the `=` sign appears in the context of a *declaration*, then you have initialization. So for instance `string str = "hello"` is an initialization - pretty much like `string str("Hello")` - because it's in the context of the declaration of `str`. However, `str = "hello"` is an assignment, since you're not declaring a new variable here.

Comment: I see the difference. Does `string str = "hello"` equals to: first, do default initialization `string str()` then do the copy assignment `str = "hello"`?

Comment: @Dreamer: Nope. As I wrote in the previous comment, `string str="hello"` is the same as `string str("hello")`. Default initialization + assignment would be: `string str; str = "hello"`.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Actually, `string str="hello"` is the same as `string str(string("hello"))` — while for `string` it won't make a difference (the extra copy will be optimized away anyway), it does for classes where the copy constructor does not exist/is not accessible.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to *assign* the value of one string to another, which has already been initialized. The syntax for that is

```
std::string s1 = ....;
std::string s2 = ....;
s2 = s1; // OK, assignment
```

whereas you are attempting the equivalent of

```
s2(s1); // error, this is no way to assign s1 to s2
```

and that is just invalid syntactically in this context. You cannot *initialize* objects that have already been constructed.